# Tree Creation Python Solution

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a list of strings

```
data = ['1', '8TUV', '0', '0', '4GHI', '6MNO', '8TUV', '5JKL', '8TUV', '6MNO', '5JKL']
```

Expected Output Figure:

```
                               1
                           / |  |    \ 
                          8  T   U     V
                         /   |    |      \
                        0    0    0        0
                       /     |     \        \
                      0      0       0       0 
                    // |\  // |\   // |\   // |\
                   4 G H I 4 G H I 4 G H I 4 G H I
             //// ////||||\\\\
           6MNO 6MNO 6MNO 6MNO 
                   

Now 4 will have children [6,M,N,O], G will have children [6,M,N,O], H will have children [6,M,N,O], I will have children [6,M,N,O].
```

The structure is like,
The first element of data is the root.
The second element is the child of the first element. If the second element has length > 1, say length 'l' then the first element will have l children.
l[0] .. l[n] children will have the third element(s) as children, so and so forth.
Leaf elements should be like 6MNO (data[9])

```
 6    M     N   O
|||| |||| |||| ||||
5JKL 5JKL 5JKL 5JKL [Leaf elements, since no element exists after 5JKL in data]
```

Each 'i+1' element in the list **data** is a child of the 'i' element. If the length of the i+1 element == 0 then, the 'i' element of data has 1 child, however, if the length of the 'i+1' element has a length greater than 1 then the 'i' element will have the number of children equal to the length of the i+1 element.

Another Example:
[image: tree sample]

This is my class to represent the structure of an individual node.

```
class Node:
  def __init__(self,c='%',children={}):
    self.c = c #c => character
    self.children = children # 
    }
```

```
Node(character='1',
children: {
8: Node(character:'8',children:{}),
T: Node(character:'T',children:{}),
U: Node(character:'U',children:{}),
V: Node(character:'V',children:{})
})
```

```
I want (came up with this structure) a tree structure in this way (expected output)

{
  c='1',
  children={
    'T': {
      c = 'T',
      children = {
        c='0',
        children = {
          c = '0',
          children = {
            'G'={},
            'H'={},
            'I'={}
          }
        }
      }
    },
    'U': {
      c = 'U',
      children:{
       .
      .
      }
    },
    'V': {
      c = 'V',
      children:{
      .
      .
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I know I need to use recursion and DFS, but I am unable to think of a solution. Any suggestions/feedback that would be really helpful.

My logic:

```
root = Node(data[0]) // 1 
def dfs(node,data):
  if not data or len(data) == 0:
    return node.children
  for i in range(1,len(data)):
    node.children[i-1] = dfs(node,data[i:])
  #now current node should be list(node.children.keys())[0] to #list(node.children.keys())[n]
  for k,v in node.children.items():
    node = node.children[k]
# perform call recursive function again. 
dfs(root,data)
```

Comment: "but I am unable to think of a solution" is not acceptable for a Stack Overflow question - you are expected to make an effort to solve the problem, and show what you tried, along with your reasoning to get that far, and pinpoint exactly where you are stuck. Please (re-)read [ask].

Comment: Please provide a *complete* input, and *corresponding* output (complete). It is currently not clear (for example) how you identify a leaf. And as said above, include your attempt and description of what is the problem with it. We can put effort in answering, but the effort must come from both sides.

Comment: How does the figure match `data`?  I don't get it. `data` has two entries with "8TUV", but I only see it once in the figure. `data` has twice "6MNO", bit the figure has it 4 times. The figure has many more zeroes... Can you please make it consistent?

Comment: You write *"5JKL  Leaf elements, since no element exists after it"*, but how does `data` determine that "no element exists after it"?

Comment: Um so we know the data is a list of strings, ['1', '8TUV', '0', '0', '4GHI', '6MNO', '8TUV', '5JKL', '8TUV', '6MNO', '5JKL']. Technically, each i+1 element in data is a child of i element (0<=i<=len(data)-1). If 'i+1' element is of length == 1 then i has one child, but if i+1 element has length greater than 1 then i element children equal to the length i +1. 
Another example, if data = ['0','1','0','ABC'], the tree would be 
0 -> 1 -> 0 -> [A,B,C] [second 0 has three children; 'A', "B', 'C']

Answer (score 0):

A couple of interesting points will actually save you from having to create your own Class node and you can instead just print the tree diagram given the list of elements.

Interesting points ->

1.) A tree has no cycle. Therefore each node can be visited once if the walk starts from the root. (Node marking doesn't need to be done)

2.) Each node is an independent d-ary node (meaning the only limit of branching factor for level-i position-j is the number of elements in the (i+1)th index of the list of elements

3.) Cascading effect -> if i-th level led to x_i branches, and i+1-th level led to x_(i+1) branches, then the number of time the number of times a unit (over here a unit is an element of the list which in turn is a string/character) will occur in the i+2th level is -> x_0 * x_1 * ...x_(i+1) * sizeOf(unit)

**Ergo**

Given some input ->

```
data = ['1', '8TUV', '0', '0', '4GHI', '6MNO', '8TUV', '5JKL', '8TUV', '6MNO', '5JKL']
```

print '1' - 1 time

print '8TUV' - 1 time (split into '8', 'T', 'U', 'V')

print '0' - 1 * 4 times

print '0' - 1 * 4 * 1 times

print '4GHI' - 1 * 4 * 1 * 1 times (split into '4', 'G', 'H', 'I')

print '6MNO' - 1 * 4 * 1 * 1 * 4 times (split into '6', 'M', 'N', '0')

...

Comment: I like your ideas, just a bit confused about the third point "cascading effect". According to the figure I have given, the tree is created with the input list 
For eg: if data = ['0','1','ABC'], the output should be 0(root) -> 1 -> A,B,C [children of 1]

Comment: Cascading here means that the number of times the ith element is repeated in the tree depends on the branching factor for the predecessor of that level. If you data instead was ['0','11','ABC'], you'll have to list (A,B,C) twice. Similarly if you had ['0','11','111','ABC' ]you'll have to list (A,B,C) 2 * 3 times